# Angularjs: Unable to iterate or get results from service result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

guys
I'm new to Angularjs, here's some code of my new single-page app. But I think I'm not doing it right.
Here is my gode:

```
var TownApp=angular.module('TownApp',['ngRoute','ngResource']);

TownApp.service('Town', function($http) {
    this.all = function() {
        return $http.get('/database.json').then(function(response){
          return response.data;
        })
    };
});

var HomeCtrl = TownApp.controller('HomeCtrl',function($scope,Town){
  $scope.towns = Town.all();
});
var TownCtrl = TownApp.controller('TownCtrl',function($scope, $routeParams, Town){
  console.log(Town.all().length)
  $scope.towns = Town.all();
  console.log($scope.towns.length)

  //........

})
TownApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routes) {

  $routes.when('/',{
    templateUrl : 'welcome.html',
    controller : 'HomeCtrl'
  }).when('/town/:townId',{
    templateUrl : 'town.html',
    controller : 'TownCtrl'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
  });

}]);
```

So, the question is you can see those two console logs in Town controller, they all returned 'undefined'. So that I can't iterate or get values from `Town.all()`. But its working perfect on HomeController.

I've treid with both service and factory. I think I'm just doing it in wrong way? 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you try to retrieve the data from the server in a synchronous way, which doesn't work in angular (nor in javascript in general).

Change the service code to:

```
TownApp.service('Town', function($http) {
    this.all = function() {
        return $http.get('/database.json');
    };
});
```

And then change the controller code to:

```
 TownApp.controller('HomeCtrl',function($scope,Town){
    Town.all().then(function(response)) {
      $scope.towns = response.data;
      console.log($scope.towns.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Shay, I'm now getting `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` from the console, what might be the issue you think?

Comment: Have you checked what you get in response.data. It's probably not the array you're looking for. Put a breakpoint on the $scope.towns = response.data; line and check what response contains.

Comment: Iv changed all data from async to static JSON string, saved much time. I will sure get back to async service stuff later while I finish this project. Thanks again for you help!

Answer (score 1):

`Town.all()` returns a promise. A promise is like a value to be returned some time in the future. It's not directly the value. It's an object that can be used to retrieve the value.

So instead of

```
$scope.towns = Town.all();
```

you need:

```
Town.all()
    .then(function(response){
        //if the promise we are dealing with is the promise that was directly 
        //returned from the $http call, then we need response.data
        //if it was projected to hold `response.data` before (as in the initial question)
        //then "response" here is already holding our data.
        $scope.towns = response;    
    });
```

Comment: No need to assign Town.all() to `$scope.towns`

Comment: Hi, Christoph, but `response.data` is returning `undefined`. :(

Comment: @Still.Wang yeah, that actually depends on how you project the promise before. If you make a projection `return response.data` then in the next step the parameter is already your response data. If you take the raw promise that is returned from the `$http` call then you need to take `response.data`. But according to your initial example you would only need `response`. I will correct that in my answer.